# What is the proper usage of a verb when the subject is singular but its meaning is plural?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

I am unsure of this rule, and would like a straight answer or resource; this is not a peeve. This appears today in google trends:  *A new set of icons suggest that voice-activated sharing to social networks could be on the cards*. Should not the proper term be *suggests* since the subject is actually 'set' not 'icons'?

Read more: http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/hidden-code-hints-new-google-now-features/#ixzz3OdX8zghU

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks like a peeve. A number of people believe that since *"**a** number"* is singular, this sentence should use ***believes***, not ***believe***. But probably only a *small* number.

Comment: ... as in it covers what this covers.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage when the subject is a singular object — such as *A new set* — is the corresponding conjugation, which, according to at least two sources, is *suggests*.

[GingerSoftware Grammar Checker](http://www.gingersoftware.com/grammarcheck) and [Reverso Grammar checker](http://www.reverso.net/spell-checker/english-spelling-grammar/) both correct this as follows:
Source:

> A new set of icons *suggest* that voice-activated sharing to social networks could be on the cards.

Correction:

> A new set of icons *suggests* that voice-activated sharing to social networks could be on the cards.

So, *A new set of icons suggests that voice-activated sharing to social networks could be on the cards.* is technically correct, online at least, on a couple of sites at least...

Comment: Automated grammar checkers are _not_ a reliable guide for English language usage.

Answer (score 0):

Recognizing the validity of the first answer:

*set* implies a plurality of icons, all suggesting..., so some people use the plural form of the verb. Technically incorrect; still communicates.

Answer (score 0):

Phrases of the form "a(n) [singular noun denoting a group] of [plural noun]" are sometimes treated as singular, and sometimes as plural. One major factor is the first noun; to take an extreme example, I believe that all forms of English allow "a lot of people agree" and forbid *"a lot of people agrees". Another major factor is the language variety; UK speakers are typically much more willing than US speakers to use a plural verb with a syntactically-singular subject.

In your specific example, I think the deciding question would be — is it the actual *set* of icons that suggests the change? Or is it the icons *in* that set? If the latter, then "a new set of icons" will generally be treated as plural.